# Medical ID Fragment not updating after successfully retrieving data from database

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

So I've built a health application which utilizes fragments. I have a separate activity which can update a users medical ID. This data is stored in a realtime database inside firebase. The problem is that the data does not show up in my Medical ID fragment even after being retrieved.

I need the application to update this specific fragment after the medical ID has been updated, there maybe some fragment refresh method that can help with this, the ones I've used have been deprecated.

Class where the fragment is inflated:

```
package com.example.managinghealthapplicationv1;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class MedicalIDFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_medicalid, container, false);


}
}
```

Class where the fragment activity data is retrieved from the database (the Rootkey reference is correct):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class RetrieveMedicalInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
    private CircleImageView userProfileImage;
    private String currentUserID;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference RootKey;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_medicalid);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        userProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.medical_image);

        a = findViewById(R.id.rname);
        b = findViewById(R.id.rage);
        c = findViewById(R.id.rheight);
        d = findViewById(R.id.rweight);
        e = findViewById(R.id.rbloodtype);
        f = findViewById(R.id.rcondition);
        g = findViewById(R.id.rreaction);
        h = findViewById(R.id.rmedication);

        RootKey = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("User Medical Profile");
        RootKey.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);

                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue().toString();
                String height = dataSnapshot.child("height").getValue().toString();
                String weight = dataSnapshot.child("weight").getValue().toString();
                String bloodtype = dataSnapshot.child("bloodtype").getValue().toString();
                String medcondition = dataSnapshot.child("medcondition").getValue().toString();
                String medreaction = dataSnapshot.child("medreaction").getValue().toString();
                String medmedication = dataSnapshot.child("medmedication").getValue().toString();

                a.setText(name);
                b.setText(age);
                c.setText(height);
                d.setText(weight);
                e.setText(bloodtype);
                f.setText(medcondition);
                g.setText(medreaction);
                h.setText(medmedication);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Here is the layout xml file of the medical ID:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RetrieveMedicalInfo"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/medical_image"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="157dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="158dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="158dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blank_profile"
        app:civ_border_color="#ff7f7f"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rname"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="111dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/medical_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rage"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="406dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Age"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rheight"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="405dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Height (cm)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rweight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rweight"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="406dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Weight (kg)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rbloodtype"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Blood Type"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rcondition"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rcondition"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Medical Conditions"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rreaction"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rreaction"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Allergies &amp; Reactions"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rmedication"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rmedication"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Medications"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="435dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="97dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="97dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="435dp"
        android:text="Height"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="435dp"
        android:text="Weight"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Medical ID information updated in activity:

[image]

Doesn't show any changes in the Medical ID fragment:

[image]

Lastly this is the structure of the firebase database:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If it's any use I can give the github link to my project

Comment: update your firebase realtime database structure.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine in the realtime database, I think there is an issue with the actual fragment showing data from the database. I have updated the post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not affiliated with the medical ID fragment. Try this

MedicalIDFragment

```
  package com.example.managinghealthapplicationv1;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


    public class MedicalIDFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
    private CircleImageView userProfileImage;
    DatabaseReference RootKey;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_medicalid, container, false);

         userProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.medical_image);

        a = view.findViewById(R.id.rname);
        b = view.findViewById(R.id.rage);
        c = view.findViewById(R.id.rheight);
        d = view.findViewById(R.id.rweight);
        e = view.findViewById(R.id.rbloodtype);
        f = view.findViewById(R.id.rcondition);
        g = view.findViewById(R.id.rreaction);




        RootKey = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("User Medical Profile");
        RootKey .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
         @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
              if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                  {

              String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
              String age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue().toString();
              String height = dataSnapshot.child("height").getValue().toString();
              String weight = dataSnapshot.child("weight").getValue().toString();
              String bloodtype = dataSnapshot.child("bloodtype").getValue().toString();
              String medcondition = dataSnapshot.child("medcondition").getValue().toString();
              String medreaction = dataSnapshot.child("medreaction").getValue().toString();
              String medmedication = dataSnapshot.child("medmedication").getValue().toString();
              String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                 a.setText(name);
                 b.setText(age);
                 c.setText(height);
                 d.setText(weight);
                 e.setText(bloodtype);
                 f.setText(medcondition);
                 g.setText(medreaction);
                 h.setText(medmedication);
                 Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);

                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                            {

                            }
                        });

    }
return view;
    }
    }
```

MedicalIDFragment fragment

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MedicalIDFragment"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/medical_image"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="157dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="158dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="158dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blank_profile"
        app:civ_border_color="#ff7f7f"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rname"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="111dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/medical_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rage"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="406dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Age"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rheight"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="405dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Height (cm)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rweight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rweight"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="406dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Weight (kg)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rbloodtype"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Blood Type"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rcondition"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rcondition"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Medical Conditions"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rreaction"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rreaction"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Allergies &amp; Reactions"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rmedication"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rmedication"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Medications"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="435dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="97dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="97dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="435dp"
        android:text="Height"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="435dp"
        android:text="Weight"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result (as the second screenshot posted), nothing is shown in the medical ID fragment. It seems like the activity class isn't being called into the fragment correctly, I don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: If the medical ID fragment is not displayed, you are not affiliated with the medical ID fragment. Try the above

Comment: Now it just crashes, I will run it in the debugger to see what error it gives, thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Image path /users/userid/. But ur path /users/userid/user/medical profile

Comment: So I have figured out the error, debugger says this: ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference``` This line: ```userProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.medical_image);``` results in an error saying findviewByID should be changed to this: ```userProfileImage = userProfileImage.findViewById(R.id.medical_image);``` then the error occurs

Comment: I have completely removed the circleimageview from the code and I still get the null object reference error but on a textview as seen here: ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'``` Now I have no clue

Comment: I have finally made it work, thank you, really! You put me in the right direction, I finally understand how fragments work.